Why did Nesuko become immune to sunlight?
In episode 1 season 4 of the anime, it's mentioned that Muzan is going to come for Nezuko because she's the only demon who got immune to sunlight. Why did this happen?

I think the mystery will be revealed in the next season by Tamayo who is herself a demon and seemed like she figured out something once she heard the news about Nezuko.

@Pablo Please check out my answer to another similar question: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/68953/how-did-nezuko-conquer-the-sun/69012#69012. It may help.

I don't believe it was ever explicitly stated how, although it's been heavily implied.
There was a scene at some point or another where Nezuko (or Nesuko, whatever your preferred spelling is) ate a blue spider lily when she was still human. It is shown that Kie (her mother) fed her a blue spider lily as an ingredient in a food, which I believe was a soup, but that's irrelevant to the story as far as I can tell. It's also been implied that Kie knew something we, the audience, did not. That's about all I know about it, though, so I'll just put it down to the Blue Spider Lily.

The blue spider lily was the plant which was supposed to cure Muzan?

@Pablo Yes. Kie knew something we didn't, I'm sure

At what Season/episode did that happen? I would very much like to know.

@GhibliFan007 I don't think it was shown explicitly, but it was heavily implied that she ate a spider lily in the form of a soup. My memory is fuzzy, but I'll have to go back and see.

@AustinOverton Do you think this scene is in the infinity castle arc? Because I haven't watched Infinity castle arc, it's not yet released in my region.

@GhibliFan007 possibly. I don't remember explicily.

@AustinOverton Although I still can't find the scene in the anime, many sources stated that the scene is in the second data book of Demon Slayer. I guess it's not in either the anime or manga but in supplemental sources.

@GhibliFan007 I suppose I must've imagined it then, my apologies!

@AustinOverton You probably didn't imagined it, just that you managed to get the data books. I want them soo much.

@AustinOverton Anyway, check out my answer to a similar, but newer question on this site: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/68953/how-did-nezuko-conquer-the-sun/69012#69012.
